# weird error causes no responding

Tags: python, pygame

```
envface1=pygame.image.load(p1)
envface2=pygame.image.load(p2)
envface1=pygame.transform.scale(envface1,(768,400))
envface2=pygame.transform.scale(envface2,(768,400))
start = timeit.default_timer()
window.blit(txt[0],(0,0))
window.blit(envface1,(0,400))
window.blit(envface2,(800,400))
pygame.display.flip()
display=False
while not display:
    #delete the print will make it no responding
    print
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        display=True
        print "1"
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        display=True
        print "2"
end=timeit.default_timer()
print end-start

pygame.quit()
```

For this part of code, I am trying to make something that user can choose the picture they like and print the result out. But in the while loop, when I delete the line with "print" only and run it, the program will down and make it no responding. Why would this happen?

Comment: If you don't press `K_LEFT` or `K_RIGHT` (assuming you did that correctly), you will be stuck in an infinite loop since `display` will never be `True`.

Answer (score 1):

As Cyber explained, you have a while loop that runs while `display` is false. However, since you don't modify `display` at all inside the loop, you've effectively created an infinite loop.

Your observation that the program will not respond is caused by the fact that nothing happens in the infinite loop unless a key is pressed.

Comment: the thing is when I pressed the key, it produced nothing and stuck